# mysqli_real_escape_string not escaping anything

Tags: php, mysqli

I am using [mysqli_real_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php) to escape single and double quotes etc. but it is not escaping anything. My code is as follows

```
$con = mysqli_connect("ip","db","pw","db");
$formtext = $_POST['formtext'];
$formtext = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $formtext);
mysqli_query($con, "INSERT into table (formtext) VALUES ('$formtext')")
    or die();
```

After inserting into the table the 'formtext' field contains no escapes (backslashes).
What are the possible reasons for this to be happening?

Comment: what is your input and inserted output?

Comment: what you mean "no escapes", can you show data?

Comment: Why not just use prepared statements? http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php

Comment: My input was something like " \n, \r, \, ', ". " Output exactly the same. By "no escapes" I mean no backslashes where they should be. I plan on using prepared statements, this is bugging me though...

Comment: @KevinGulling .... that means mysqli_real_escape_string done his job perfectly

Comment: How did you observe the output?

Comment: Print out the generated query instead and you’ll see the escapes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data saved to the database **will *not* contain "escapes"** or escape sequences or extraneous slashes.

The database ***will* contain the *actual data* supplied**, which is the point of the function: to escape the input *for use as SQL string content* in an SQL statement.

> [mysqli_real_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php) escapes special characters in a string *for use in an SQL statement* [as string literal content], taking into account the current charset of the connection.

---

If the point is to *change* data (and if so, be precise on what the *change* should be) - noting that "real_escape" or (better) [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) should *still* be used anyway - then use the appropriate function for the task.

Comment: So to simplify your answer, would it be correct to say that in the code above, mysqli_real_escape_string is working correctly, and there are not supposed to be backslashes? I will look into the parameterized queries. (Wasn't it required to escape a string before an insert at one point when mysqli came out?)

Comment: @KevinGulling Yes, that is correct. It escapes the string *as it is in SQL syntax*, which does not (and should not) change the value inserted. It just ensures it's valid SQL string content and mitigates SQL Injection.